# Query list view webpart by Page Header/Title using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list-view

Struggling to get the page header as a variable into a List view Web Part query, code below, note that i want the header above the main content area, not the actual HTML title (it is different) pic below.

The Query works fine if i type the page header in manually, so the data is there just need to insert some code that pulls the page header to string:

```
             <Query>
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="Client_x0020_Code"/>
                        <Value Type="Text">THIS TEXT NEEDS TO BE A VAR</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
            </Query>
```

[image]

Have tried like pasting in

```
     <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="CurrentViewTitle" runat="server"/>
```

But it breaks the page.

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to do? Are you working on Site Page code directly using SPD? Or you are using some object model?

Comment: Yep working on a page directly in SPD (it will be a template), it has a list view a the top and i want to filter it by the page header text

Comment: Just for clarification, why you want to filter based on Page title? Cant you create a page, place the LVWP, pass the filter as query string, use List view filter WP using query string and finally place a JS at the bottom which will replace Page tile using query string?

Comment: is there any hard rule that you have to go by Page title only?

Comment: The structure of the site is a main list, and then doc libraries with a LVWP back to that main list, i want the list to be filtered by the doc library's name. This is so we can save the finished doc library as a template and just create new ones that will bring in records from the list relating to that doc library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle with the SPD, finally I got the solution for you. The solution is made for Site Pages. Follow the steps:

1. Open the Site Page in SPD.
2. Search for `ParameterBinding` tag and at the bottom add another tag having this code: `<ParameterBinding Name="TestTitle" Location="Control(wikiPageNameEditTextBox)" />`
3. Now open the XSLT List View WP and add Caml Query to it. I am using single query where checking for Title equals page title. My query looks like this:

`<Where>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
                    <Value Type="Text">{TestTitle}</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Where>`

4. Save the page in designer and run the page on browser.

If you change the title of the page to the matching item title, it will display the item.

In addition to this, I also figured out if the text box having ID is not available on page, then you can create a custom text box within span having ID `wikiPageNameEdit` and add JS below it to add page title.

So the final code look like this in SPD:

[image]

And the output of code is following:
https://i.imgur.com/rpJ7ACo.mp4

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, its not quite working but i think this is nearly the solution i need - it doesnt match because the page title is actually "XXXX - All documents" (its a library), is there a call we can make that returns the page header rather than the html title? ie Client-Template instead of Client-Template - All Documents, or is there are way of renaming the library to remove the "all documents" part of the name?   thanks again :)

Comment: In that case JS will come handy. Create a new Text Box `<asp:TextBox id="myTitle" CssClass="myTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`. Below this text box, add following script. `<script> var obj = document.getElementsByClassName('myTitle')[0]; obj.value = document.getElementById('DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').innerText.split('-').trim();`. This will solve your case.

Comment: Just Test the JS first on browser, if its throwing any error or not. As I had not test it.

Comment: And if that solves your query you can upvote and mark it as answer. :)

Comment: It didnt actually work on my current solution, i couldnt get it to make the page title correct, but this solution did work on some blank wiki pages i tested so thanks for the tips they do work. i think i'm going to try and get this to work by using subsite templates and REST to push data back to a master list - thanks for your help. +1

Comment: Can you tell, what is the exact problem you are facing now to get the title. Also if you share page code where you are trying to achieve this may help in better way..